# telerik:Radgrid AllowMultiRowSelection behaviour if user selects first row at the bottom and then row on top

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I would like to know if **telerik:Radgrid** multiple row selection property (for a range of rows - Click first row followed by Shift+Click last row) only works if the user selects first row on top of Grid followed by row at the bottom.

**what if the user select first row at the bottom and then row on top?** I expect it should also select the rows in between but in this case it only select the row on top.

**does anybody know if this is an expected AllowMultiRowSelection behaviour for telerik:RadGrid?**

the other cases (Ctrl+click) work just well,

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rg" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" >
    <ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

any help thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be issues with this. I tried it and it worked fine for me. Try this demo and mimic it: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/selecting/row-selection/defaultcs.aspx.

What is important there is that two of the rows cannot be selected and this is done intentionally, with some server code (see the RadGrid1_PreRender event handler). Make sure this is not the case with you - if you copied all the code you have also copied that too and you will need to remove it.

Comment: the demo clarifies my doubt about my mentioned scenario: "Several rows can be selected either by: ... clicking a row, holding the Shift key and clicking another row upwards/downwards", however in my case it only works for the downwards case, thank you. I will update the question as soon as I find the cause for this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: the cause of losing the selecteditems was due to **EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true"** as shown in the telerik demo link provided by @rdmpt answer.

Comment: However a new question arises, what if I still want to manage multiRowSelection at client side but want to have a postback if the user performs a single row selection?

Comment: I don't see reasons for a problem. I just tried the demo code and it works fine for me: http://screencast.com/t/k128AX9PS. Make sure you are using the latest version. Also, something like this may help if you want to cancel events and avoid postbacks on condition: http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-with-enablepostbackonrowclick-and-gridclientselectcolumn#rzDnFVhlo0am2cu5-ltrDQ. If you are still stuck, open a ticket with Telerik support :)